# how to record button presses in python to open combination lock

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Im trying to use my raspberry pi to play sounds when buttons are pushed and additionally output when the right order of button presses are made.

i've figured out the sounds pretty good and got that working but cant figure out how to program the combination lock. Any help would be appreciated to get me on the right path. (output would be setup as 26)

code thus far:

```
import os
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if (GPIO.input(17) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 /home/pi/frogjars/frog1.mp3 &')
        print("Button 1 Pressed")
        sleep(3)
    if (GPIO.input(27) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 /home/pi/frogjars/frog2.mp3 &')
        print("Button 2 Pressed")
        sleep(3)
    if (GPIO.input(22) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 /home/pi/frogjars/frog3.mp3 &')
        print("Button  3 Pressed")
        sleep(3)
    if (GPIO.input(10) == False):
        os.system('mpg123 /home/pi/frogjars/frog4.mp3 &')
        print("Button  4 Pressed")
        sleep(3)

    sleep(0.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on how you want to handle entry of the combination.  The simplest/crudest method is to append each button press to a string and then check if the combination is in the string.  Clearing the cached button presses after a timeout, or a number of presses, will require a little more complexity.

Comment: i figured it out based on your suggestion. works perfect. Thanks